# Axios is throwing an error abortSignal during the build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

I am trying to use axios in nodejs typescript project and during the build it is throwing an error `abortSignal` any fix for this issue appreciate the help

index.ts

```
export async function getAccessToken(apiConfig: any) {

        const req = {
            grant_type: apiConfig.authOptions.body.grant_type,
            client_id: apiConfig.authOptions.credentials.clientId,
            client_secret: apiConfig.authOptions.credentials.clientSecret,
            scope: apiConfig.authOptions.body.scope
        };
        const headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "appName": "Blink"
        };
        try {
            const resp: AxiosResponse = await axios.post('https://test.com//auth/oauth2/token',
            req, { headers });
            console.log(resp.data);
        } catch (err) {
            // Handle Error Here
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
```

Error

```
node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(93,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AbortSignal'.
```

Package.json

```
"axios": "^0.24.0",
```

Comment: `index.js` shouldn't it be `index.ts`?

Comment: @ikhvjs yes it is index.ts

Comment: could you show your `tsconfig.json` please?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4304

Answer (score 0):

Try providing `abortController` signal in the axios parameter:

```
const abortController=new AbortController;
const resp: AxiosResponse = await axios.post(
  'https://test.com//auth/oauth2/token',
  req,
  { headers },
  signal:abortController.signal
);
```